# event.preventDefault() не срабатывает с submit. На javascript

Tags: javascript

Не срабатывает event.preventDefault()

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.querySelectorAll('form input[name="text"]');
  var submit = document.querySelector('form input[type="submit"]');
  var form = new Form(input);
  submit.addEventListener('click', form.check);


}

function Form(input) {
  this.input = input;


  this.check = function() {

    for (var i = 0; i > input.length; i++) {
      if (this.input[i].value == '') {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.input[i].classList.add('error');
      } else {
        this.input[i].classList.remove('error');
      }
    }
  };


}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input name="text" type="name" placeholder="Введите имя"><br>
  <input name="text" type="text" placeholder="Введите почту"><br>
  <input name="text" type="text" placeholder="Введите телефон"><br>
  <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь, что помимо проблемы с контекстом `form.check`, Вы обратили внимание на такие мелочи как параметр `event` в функции-обработчике клика и условие в цикле `for.`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('form input[type="text"]');
  var submit = document.querySelector('form input[type="submit"]');
  var form = new Form(inputs);
  submit.addEventListener('click', form.check.bind(form));
}

function Form(inputs) {
  this.inputs = inputs;

  this.check = function(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.inputs.length; i++) {
      if (this.inputs[i].value == '') {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.inputs[i].classList.add('error');
      } else {
        this.inputs[i].classList.remove('error');
      }
    }
  };
}
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя"><br>
  <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Введите почту"><br>
  <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Введите телефон"><br>
  <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но ест вопрос. submit.addEventListener('click', form.check.bind(form)); откуда взялся bind? И зачем вы передаёте в параметрах функции опять (form).

Comment: @ВладимирБогданович Потому что если передать просто ссылку на `form.check`, то эта функция будет вызываться в контексте, отличающемся от объекта `form`. И доступа к `this.inputs` не будет.

Comment: Я так понимаю что this.check = function(event){event.preventDefault();} это callback? Просто для меня не понятно как может функция вызывать функцию из самой себя. Мне ломает это мозг.

Comment: @ВладимирБогданович э-э-э, в данном случае термин "callback" обычно не используют, хотя в каком-то смысле функция, которую назначают обработчиком события может считаться callback-ом. Но лучше называть это "event handler".

Answer (score 1):

у тебя есть ошибки с контекстом..я this заменил на self( вообще лучше через bind но, так  быстрее и понятнее), что бы работало, и функция забирающая event не принимала никаких аргументов.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.querySelectorAll('form input[name="text"]');
  var submit = document.querySelector('form input[type="submit"]');
  var form = new Form(input);
  submit.addEventListener('click', form.check);
}

function Form(input) {
  this.input = input;
  let self = this;
  this.check = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.defaultPrevented);
    for (var i = 0; i > input.length; i++) {
      if (self.input[i].value == '') {
        self.input[i].classList.add('error');
      } else {
        self.input[i].classList.remove('error');
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input name="text" type="name" placeholder="Введите имя"><br>
  <input name="text" type="text" placeholder="Введите почту"><br>
  <input name="text" type="text" placeholder="Введите телефон"><br>
  <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если несколько форм

```js
window.onload = function(e){
 var form = document.querySelectorAll('form');
 [].forEach.call(form, function(item, index){
  item.addEventListener('submit', check)
 });
}; 

var check = function(e){
 var input = this.querySelectorAll('input'),
  error = false;
 [].forEach.call(input, function(item, index){
  if(item.value.length){
   item.classList.remove('error');
  }else{
   error = true;
   item.classList.add('error');
  }
 });
 if(error){
  e.preventDefault();
  return !1;
 }
};
```

```css
input {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.error {
 border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <input  name="text" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя"><br>
    <input name="text" type="email" placeholder="Введите почту"><br>
    <input name="text" type="tel" placeholder="Введите телефон"><br>
 <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
<form action="">
    <input  name="text" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя"><br>
    <input name="text" type="email" placeholder="Введите почту"><br>
    <input name="text" type="tel" placeholder="Введите телефон"><br>
 <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```